# "Error When Automating 'composer update' with 'expect': 'send: spawn id not open' Issue"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation, expect

I am getting error of `send: spawn id exp4 not open while executing "send "yes\r""` while using the command 'spawn sudo composer update --no-plugins --no-scripts' using the expect command and hence the process terminates without being completed.

Note: **Composer** in Snipe-IT is a vital tool that helps manage and install the necessary PHP dependencies to run the application. It ensures that Snipe-IT can run correctly with all the required components.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update
sudo apt install git apache2 -y
sudo systemctl start apache2 && sudo systemctl enable apache2
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client -y
sudo systemctl start mariadb && sudo systemctl enable mariadb

#mysql_secure_installation automated

sudo apt install expect -y

SECURE_MYSQL=$(expect -c "
set timeout 5
spawn sudo mysql_secure_installation
expect \"Enter current password for root : \"
send \"\r\"
expect \"Switch to unix_socket authentication\"
send \"n\r\"
expect \"Change the root password?\"
send \"n\r\"
expect \"Remove anonymous users?\"
send \"y\r\"
expect \"Disallow root login remotely?\"
send \"y\r\"
expect \"Remove test database and access to it?\"
send \"y\r\"
expect \"Reload privilege tables now?\"
send \"y\r\"
expect eof
")

echo "$SECURE_MYSQL"

sudo apt install -y php php-cli php-fpm php-json php-common php-mysql php-zip php-gd php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath php-bz2 php-intl php-opcache php-pdo php-calendar php-ctype php-exif php-ffi php-fileinfo php-ftp php-iconv php-mysqli php-phar php-posix php-readline php-shmop php-sockets php-sysvmsg php-sysvsem php-sysvshm php-tokenizer php-curl php-ldap

sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

#Database Configuration
sudo mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE snipeitdb;"
sudo mysql -u root -e "CREATE USER snipeituser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'snipeitpass';"
sudo mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON snipeitdb.* TO snipeituser@localhost;"
sudo mysql -u root -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"

cd /var/www/
sudo git clone https://github.com/snipe/snipe-it snipe-it
cd snipe-it

sudo cp .env.example .env
sudo sed -i "s|^\\(DB_DATABASE=\\).*|\\1snipeitdb|" "/var/www/snipe-it/.env"
sudo sed -i "s|^\\(DB_USERNAME=\\).*|\\1snipeituser|" "/var/www/snipe-it/.env"
sudo sed -i "s|^\\(DB_PASSWORD=\\).*|\\1snipeitpass|" "/var/www/snipe-it/.env"
sudo sed -i "s|^\\(APP_URL=\\).*|\\1|" "/var/www/snipe-it/.env"

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/snipe-it
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/snipe-it

COMPOSER_1=$(expect -c "
spawn sudo composer update --no-plugins --no-scripts
expect \"Continue as root/super user?\"
send \"yes\r\"
expect eof
")
echo "$COMPOSER_1"
sleep 10

COMPOSER_2=$(expect -c "
spawn sudo composer install --no-dev --prefer-source --no-plugins --no-scripts
expect \"Continue as root/super user?\"
send \"yes\r\"
expect eof
")
echo "$COMPOSER_2"
sleep 10

KEY_GENERATE=$(expect -c "
spawn sudo php artisan key:generate
expect \"Do you really wish to run this command?\"
send \"yes\r\"
expect eof
")
echo "$KEY_GENERATE"

sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf

cat << EOF > /etc/apache2/sites-available/snipeit.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName pspradhan.cloud
  DocumentRoot /var/www/snipe-it/public
  <Directory /var/www/snipe-it/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
EOF


sudo a2ensite snipe-it.conf

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ./storage
sudo chmod -R 755 ./storage

sudo systemctl restart apache2

sudo apt purge expect -y
```

Comment: The given prompt doesn't match what the program displays...

Comment: Hi @Shawn, what changes should i make to the code to make it work ?

Comment: Hi @sexpect-ExpectforShells, how is it different from expect and how it can solve my issues ?

Comment: I'd toss the shell part and write the entire thing in tcl/expect. :) (It kind of looks like the spawned program is finishing before the `send` command, but I don't know anything about this `composer`)

Comment: where does `spawn sudo php artisan key:generate` come at the end of the output?

Comment: there's also `spawn sudo composer install` in the output. please post your real script and output, or a [repro] please.

Comment: @Shawn, Composer in Snipe-IT is a vital tool that helps manage and install the necessary PHP dependencies to run the application. It ensures that Snipe-IT can run correctly with all the required components. 
Please help me in writing the expect blocks for both the composer processes.

Comment: @pynexj, I have updated the complete script

Comment: enable debugging by changing `expect -c "spawn sudo composer update ...` to `expect -d -c "...` and see what's in `$COMPOSER_1`.

Comment: based on current info i suspect `composer update` would not prompt `Continue as root/super user?`.

Comment: @pynexj, I have tried `composer update` without root privileges, but it cannot write or read data from `/var/www/snipe-it(working directory)` without root privileges.

Comment: @pynexj, modifying to `expect -d -c "...` not working. The problem is that the control is going out of `COMPOSER_1` expect block even though it has not been finished executing completely and the `COMPOSER_2` starts executing and it also finishes once the send command `yes` is feeded to the prompt. It is not waiting for the completion of either of blocks.

Comment: just post output of `expect -d -c ...` so we can see if there's anything wrong. not sure if `expect -d` would send debug info to stderr but you can just `2>&1` to get all the output.

Comment: @pynexj Actually now the problem has been solved. I have simply put the non interactive flag(-n) after composer and hence the process give no prompts, executes in root privileges.